# UIImage created with animatedImageWithImages have bugs?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

Recently I found sometimes my gif image not shown. So I write a test code for it:

```
import UIKit
import ImageIO

extension UIImage {
    static func gifImageArray(data: NSData) -> [UIImage] {
        let source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(data, nil)!
        let count = CGImageSourceGetCount(source)
        if count <= 1 {
            return [UIImage(data: data)!]
        } else {
            var images = [UIImage]();   images.reserveCapacity(count)
            for i in 0..<count {
                let image = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(source, i, nil)!
                images.append( UIImage(CGImage: image) )
            }
            return images;
        }
    }

    static func gifImage(data: NSData) -> UIImage? {
        let gif = gifImageArray(data)
        if gif.count <= 1 {
            return gif[0]
        } else {
            return UIImage.animatedImageWithImages(gif, duration: NSTimeInterval(gif.count) * 0.1)
        }
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    let _gifData : NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d3/Newtons_cradle_animation_book_2.gif")!)!
    lazy var _gifImageArray : [UIImage] = UIImage.gifImageArray(self._gifData)
    lazy var _gifImage : UIImage = UIImage.gifImage(self._gifData)!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let table = UITableView(frame: self.view.bounds, style: .Plain)
        table.dataSource = self
        table.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(table)
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1000;
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1;
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let identifier = "cell"
        var cell : UITableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier);
        if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
        }

        if let imageView = cell.imageView {
            /** 1. use the same UIImage object created by animatedImageWithImages
                the image disappear when reuse, and when touching cell, it reappear. */
            imageView.image = self._gifImage

            /** 2. create different UIImage by using same image array. this still not work */
//            imageView.image = UIImage.animatedImageWithImages(self._gifImageArray, duration: NSTimeInterval(self._gifImageArray.count) * 0.1)

            /** 3. create different UIImage from data, this seems work
                but use a lot of memories. and seems it has performance issue. */
//            imageView.image = UIImage.gifImage(self._gifData)

            /** 4. use same image array as imageView's animationImages.
                this kind works, but have different api than just set image.
                and when click on cell, the animation stops.    */
//            imageView.image = self._gifImageArray[0]
//            imageView.animationImages = self._gifImageArray
//            imageView.startAnimating()
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

Notice in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, I tried different way to set imageView.

when I po object in lldb, I notice the animated imageView have a **CAKeyframeAnimation**. does this makes a tip?

How can I make the gif shown perfectly? Any suggestion would be helpful.

Here is a preview: after scroll, gif disappear, and reappear when touch

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After I tried many times, I have finally figured out that I need to change:

```
imageView.image = self._gifImage
```

to:

```
imageView.image = nil // this is the magical!
imageView.image = self._gifImage
```

just set image to **nil** before set to new image, and the animation work!! It's just like a magical!

This is definitely apple's bug.

Answer (score 0):

try by replacing `imageView` with `myImageview` or other name because cell have default `imageView` property so when you call `cell.imageView` then it returns cell's default imageview i think.  so change your cell's imageview's variable name. hope this will help :)

Comment: Thank you for reply! But  unfortunately, cell.imageView isn't the reason. In fact, In my project, I use a custom ImageView. Here cell.imageView just is a convenience.

Comment: what I am saying, if you are using custom `ImageView` and gives it outlet name as `imageView` then it is possible that it create ambiguity. I have face issue like this. i have custom imageview with outlet nae=me `imageView` in my custom cell and output was same like screenshot which you have post in question. that's why i am suggesting it

Comment: There is no outlet view. this just a Xcode single view template project, and all code is posted here. I have also checked and tried replacing names. Name isn't the reason. Still thanks for you help!

Comment: r u displaying this images in cell's default imageview? if yes then try once by taking another custom imageview and check your constrains also once. it may also create this kind of problem

Comment: Thank you! Myself finally figured out the solution. the answer is need to set to nil before set image! This should be apple's bug, but now it works. Thank for you patience and help! :)

Answer (score -2):

maybe image class need SDAnimatedImage instead of UIImage